# Extracting polygons by attribute in batch processing using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Reference taken: https://www.bradley365.com/qgis/split-layer-by-attribute.html

I took reference from above mentioned site and wrote:

```
import processing
input = 'D:\Geo_Data\maps-master-Saikat\maps-master\States'
field= 'State_Name'
operator = 0
value = 'Goa'
output = 'C:\Users\rpatro\Desktop\osm\Output'

processing.runalg('qgis:extractbyattribute',input,field,operator,value,output)
```

But its showing:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

I am a bit new to scripting and all.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? Also, you should escape your paths with `r` if using backward slashes (i.e. `r'C:\Users\rpatro\Desktop\osm\Output'`)

Comment: Using Version 2.18

Comment: The `input` needs to be vector data such as a shapefile, you have defined it as a directory.

Answer (score 2):

As Joseph noted with the input variable needs to be a vector layer (shapefile or some other vector layer), in addition the output needs to point to a vector format file too:

```
import processing
input = r'D:\Geo_Data\maps-master-Saikat\maps-master\States\inputShpName.shp'
field= 'State_Name'
operator = 0
value = 'Goa'
output = r'C:\Users\rpatro\Desktop\osm\Output\outputShpName.shp'

processing.runalg('qgis:extractbyattribute',input,field,operator,value,output)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but again I am stuck in batch processing.Here the code which I am using: import processing
import os
input = 'D:/Geo_Data/maps-master-Saikat/maps-master/States/India_states.shp'
field= 'State_Name'
operator = 0
output = 'C:/Users/rpatro/Desktop/osm/Output/'

unique = processing.runalg('qgis:listuniquevalues', input, field, None)
values = unique['UNIQUE_VALUES'].split(';')
for value in values:
layer = os.path.join(output,value+'.shp')
processing.runalg('qgis:extractbyattribute',input,field,operator,value,layer)

Comment: Your output variable needs to point to a file that the process will create, currently you have it only pointing to a directory, change    output = 'C:/Users/rpatro/Desktop/osm/Output/'      to      output = 'C:/Users/rpatro/Desktop/osm/Output/outputShpName.shp'